# Trying to fill a SVG map from wordpress custom categories

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, svg

I've created a custom `post_type` (destinations) with a category (locations) to provide a tree structure for my SVG map: `Continent/Country/Town`

Example locations:

```
Europe/Germany/Berlin/POST
Europe/Italiy/Sicily/POST
North-Africa/Morocco/Marrakech/POST
```

My plan was to fill the map by the country short codes like (DE for Germany, IT for Italia, LY for Libya (...).

Here is a basic example of my map: https://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/5p2xhvb8/

How could I assign a new field for my short code of the map that is attached to each location? Germany => DE, Italy => IT, Morocco => MA

I thought, I could use the description field, but I would like the description. Further, the slug could be an option, but for good urls it is also not that good.

I tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/, but if I query the categories, the new field is not included (obviously).

```
$categories = get_categories([taxonomy => 'locations']);
```

[image: Locations overview]

[image: Map Example]

Comment: _“I tried the plugin advanced custom fields, but if I query the categories, the new field is not included”_ – you can _ask_ for it, when you loop over your posts … http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe true - but I'm not looping the posts. I'm fetching categories to build the map. If the user clicks on a region, he will be redirected to see the posts by category ;)

Comment: So what do you actually want to assign a custom field/value to – the posts in those categories, or the categories themselves?

Comment: Ah! I would like to add a field to the categories themselves! I thought this would be nice to build my map.

Comment: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ doesn’t need to be inside “the loop”, you just need to feed it with the field name and the category id. So it should be quite easy, if you do it similar to what’s described here: http://naileditdesign.com/add-advanced-custom-field-category/

Comment: It works! :) You can add an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, you can add custom fields to categories (“taxonomy terms” in WP lingo) as well.

And the [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function provided by the plugin allows you to query the value of such a field for every object you might have attached it to – you just need to feed it the field name, and the id of the object (post, category, …)